# SQL Server Import Wizard

Tags: sql, sql-server

When I upload a Excel file on 'SQL Server Import and Export Wizard', I received the following error message:

```
Not enough storage is available to process this command. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070008) (Microsoft.SqlServer.DTSRuntimeWrap)
```

[image]

Can someone help me to understand and solve this error? Thanks

Comment: how many rows are you going to import?

Comment: how large is the file?  how much memory on the machine, how much allocated to ssms, how much unused allocated to ssms?  If the unused but allocated + free memory < file size, it will give this error.  The ssms import wizard actually puts the import file into memory all at once, it does not do line-by-line as can be done in application code.

Comment: For a sanity check, you can add a TOP 5 on the data load, this should at least eliminate any confusion between if this is a space problem or something else.